# Cookies mysteriously disappear

Tags: wordpress, debugging, cookies, cookie-policy

I have created a WordPress [website](https://neurochirurgiaboari.it). The lawyer in charge of the privacy policy asked me to enter a list of all the cookies used by the site. However, I have noticed a strange situation: sometimes I see fifteen or more cookies with different expiration dates, but the next day all the cookies disappear completely, even if I check from different devices. This fluctuation confuses me and I don't know if it's normal. I tried to analyze the site with some tools to verify cookies, but sometimes they detect only one, other times they detect zero. I also set access to accept all cookies in google settings. I cannot understand the reason for this inconsistency. Could you please give me some explanation or suggestion how to deal with this situation? A thousand thanks.

Comment: what is expired date and time for that cookies?

Comment: Hi Vel, you can see the expiration date here. This is the screenshot, which the hosting assistant sent me. As you can see the date is a long way off https://imgur.com/a/47dHQuq but these cookies now are nowhere to be found. Some time ago the lawyer tried to check and found other cookies which then disappeared after a few hours. Cookies that expired after 2 years